# Mutating variable with function (Ruby beginner)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How is mutation done in Ruby for this:

```
row = row.to_hash
```

I've tried **row.to_hash!**

But it doesn't work.

EDIT: Here is the code where it's in:

```
    CSV.foreach('stores.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
      row = row.to_hash
    end
```

Comment: Isn't this short enough already? In-place mutation of state may not be worth the 4 or so characters saved typing.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear.  Which class is row a member of?  What are you trying to achieve exactly?  It would help if you could give an example value of row and then explain what you want the resulting hash to look like.  Additionally, mutating variable types like this often impacts the legibility and maintainability of code; it might be better style to assign the hash to a new variable anyway.

Comment: @AdamSpiers: updated with the sample code.

Comment: @MichaelKohl: it's not just because it's short enough -- I'd like to see how mutation is done in Ruby.

Comment: Right before you do the to_hash, add the line: "puts row.inspect" and tell us the result. That will give us a better idea of what is happening.

Comment: I think this is a fairly reasonable question. The asker clearly states he or she is a beginner and there is an underlying reason for hiding mutation in some cases. It is interesting to discuss what those reasons are in order to learn more about the language.

Comment: @jaydel: Let's agree to disagree on that one (I upvoted your answer though). Hiding mutation is the opposite of what I want, which basically is neon warning signs and loud speakers ;-)

Comment: I didn't express that well I think. I was meaning that they are hiding the ability to mutate in that one case--meaning that you can't mutate the original data because there isn't a ! version of the to_hash method. And since the data in your case is simply being read out of the CSV stream, what would be mutated is temporary data anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand your question you might try:

```
rows = []
CSV.foreach('stores.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
  rows << row.to_hash
end
```

It's not actually mutation, but it does give you the output you seem to be looking for. One of the reasons for having separate methods for performing an action for new output vs. changing data in place is that in general it is wiser to have your input data be immutable. Reading from a CSV file probably doesn't fit into this paradigm cleanly (the original input is in a file somewhere), which is likely why there's no ! version of to_hash.

Optionally in my above code you could just process the hash and put the results where you want it if the input file is humongous in order to save space, rather than just shoving all the hashes into the array and then processing that array.

Answer (score -1):

We actually can't say if there is such a method. But it's most likely there isn't one, if you get a `NoMethodError`. :)

Comment: It is indeed a rails function. [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4c30304e159b2a8fafb5b3c5c8b6d996e490e657/activerecord/lib/active_record/result.rb#L23)

Comment: Well, that's from the `FlashHash` class. I don't think you're using that one.

Comment: ActiveRecord.. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4c30304e159b2a8fafb5b3c5c8b6d996e490e657/activerecord/lib/active_record/result.rb#L23

Comment: I don't even know what your statement is right now. Can you clarify on that?

Comment: It converts a row from a csv file into a hash using the header row. It's built into Rails 3.1

Comment: And you want a method, that mutates `row` into a `Hash` now?